# Im gonna panic ! Amateur

Tags: troubleshooting

Single handle shower faucet broken by force...
Discontinued but it is the nut apparently- plastic and corroded by using scissors to open for too long...what do I do....it is stuck in there and the rest is stuck in the handle....
Want to fix asap no other way to clean expect bucket....
Yes, i too just noticed there is a model number there, otherwise only know it is a jade shower column.

[image] [image]

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: You broke it then Something with scissors, we need more info but don’t panic , when you panic you always do the wrong thing!  Answer a few questions like is there an access panel? Is this a rental , you say by force but I have had renters that thought they used two much force when a valve stem broke, I was a nice guy because they were awesome tenants and fixed it and said maybe keep jerry off the weight lifting steroids as a joke (jerry was a small guy) but don’t say you broke it by force if a renter. Next we need more info and a clearer photo and what you want to try or who to call. +

Comment: Do you know where to turn off the main water. It will be the first thing you need to know and do to begin to fix this. Other than that you need to find the screws that hold the cover plate on to better access the parts you need to remove. Can you do these things? if so, more later. And the model number you mentioned would be nice to know.

Comment: A lot of shower valves and plumbing fixtures are cheap Chinese. You enjoy the nice price, then when you go back for parts, there are no parts.  Since you can't plainly identify the fixture, you are probably better off replacing the whole shebang.  With a Price Pfister.  "Oh noes, I'll have to cut up drywall", do what Victorians do. Fit a tasteful cabinet door (with a latch) in the location you'll have to cut, open the door, cut, replace fixture, close cabinet door.  You can fit the cabinet door after you cut, so you can get the position and size exact.